# raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message

Tags: python, selenium

i get this error when i'm trying to access the login page in flickr
"raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message"

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.flickr.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='yui_3_16_0_1_1619317268956_93511']")))
element.click()
```

Comment: Try to raise the timeout from 10 to 20 or 30. Update us how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

No element located by `//a[@id='yui_3_16_0_1_1619317268956_93511']` `xpath` is presented on `https://www.flickr.com/` home page.
You should use `//a[contains(@href,'signin')]` instead

Comment: the login button

Answer (score 0):

If your target is the `login` button, please use the bellow css selector:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='signin']")))
```

But if you still want use xpath, the suggest @Prophet is right.

But note css selector more faster than xpath.